# Can a Client "await" for a stream from a Server?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a basic node.js Server, thats sole purpose is to serve a single .txt file for e.g. mocking an API. Currently im using streams to "pipe" the file to the client because the file is big and i want to serve it chunk by chunk, since the file can be 1GB big and smash my RAM.

```
server.on('request', (req, res) => {
  const src = fs.createReadStream('./test.txt');
  src.pipe(res);
});
```

The client just does a fetch() req.

**My Question now:**
Is there a way to "await" a stream at client-side similiar to promises? I saw wrapping the stream kinda in to a promise but then i still would need to wait for the stream to be finished reading and would send the whole file at once?

Answer (score -1):

You might be looking for:

```
let fs = require('fs'),

server.on('request', (req, res) => {
  const src = fs.createReadStream('./test.txt');

  const reader = fs.createReadStream('README.md', {
    // Some aditional options
    //flag: 'a+',
    //encoding: 'ascii',
    //start: 0,
    //end: 64,
    //highWaterMark: 16 // Chunk size
  });

  reader.on('data', chunk => {
    console.log('chunk has been sent');
    res.write(chunk);
  });

  reader.on('end', chunk => {
    console.log('End');
    res.end();
  });
});
```

Specify the size of chunk and then send it in multiple responses until your file's been read.

I hope it helps.